# In Django, how to have CreateView only display objects created by the current user?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

The 'foods' field is a many to many field in my Models. Currently, if a User wants to create a new Meal, their selections of Foods to add are every Food in the database. Is there a way to have the create form only allow the option to only add the Foods made by the current User? I am having this issue with all of my ManytoMany fields.

views.py

```
class MealCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Meal
    success_url = '/dashboard/'
    fields = ['name', 'foods']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

in meal_form.html

```
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Meal</legend>
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Add Meal</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

in models.py

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    serving_size_g = models.DecimalField(default=100, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    protein = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    total_fats = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    saturated_fats = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    mono_unsaturated_fats = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    poly_unsaturated_fats = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    total_carbohydrates = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    energy = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    sugars = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    fiber = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    calcium = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    iron = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    magnesium = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    potassium = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    sodium = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)
    vitamin_c = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=1)


    class Meta:
        '''Limits the user from making duplicates of food'''
        unique_together = ('name', 'user', 'protein', 'total_fats', 'total_carbohydrates', 'energy', 'sugars', 'fiber', 'calcium', 
                           'iron', 'magnesium', 'potassium', 'sodium', 'vitamin_c', 'saturated_fats', 'mono_unsaturated_fats', 'poly_unsaturated_fats')



class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    foods = models.ManyToManyField(Food)
```

Comment: Yes, can you share your `Meal` and `Food` model?

Comment: yes, sorry, just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define a `ModelForm` that takes care of this:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from app.models import Food, Meal

class MealForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['foods'].queryset = Food.objects.filter(user=user)

    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        fields = ['name', 'foods']
```

Now in the `CreateView`, we can make use of this form, and also pass a value for the `user` parameter:

```
# app/views.py

from app.forms import MealForm

class MealCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Meal
    success_url = '/dashboard/'
    form_class = MealForm
    
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```